# How can I find and delete empty files?

Tags: ant

As a result of an Ant process, I generate several files (the contents of a batch svn diff).  In this case, some diff files are empty, so I would like to delete them automatically so I can concentrate only on the differences.

Is there an Ant task that would allow me to delete all files with 0 bytes easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [delete](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) task using a [fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#files) and the [size](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#rsel.size) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
<delete ...>
<fileset ...>
<size value="0" when="equal"/>
</fileset>
</delete>
```